# Command button to execute open explicit VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to VBA and found a code on internet to log the changes made in the workbook. The code is working but it is active all the time. I want to connect it to command button to start or stop the code. If there is any other way then would be welcomed.

Thank you.

Nilesh

```
Option Explicit

Public OldVal As String


Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LgDetails" Then
Application.EnableEvents = False
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Target.Address(0, 0)
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = OldVal
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("username")
    Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Date
    Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:E").AutoFit
Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub


Private Sub Workbook_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

OldVal = ActiveCell.Value

End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Static TheFormula As String
    If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then
        With Target
            TheFormula = .Formula
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    Else
        With Range("A1")
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                .Formula = TheFormula
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Nilesh, I would suggest instead of using a button, use a [check box control](http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/check-box.html) and then add a condition to the top if statement to see if the check box is checked or not. if you want to use a button, you'll need to create a macro that will run when its clicked, which could toggle a [bool constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zb8fth98.aspx) and gain check the value of that constant as an extra condition in the top IF. I hope that makes sense?

Comment: Your code is firing if there is a change in your sheets (for example `Workbook_SheetChange`). You want the code to run when a button is clicked, so replace with `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` (if the name of your button is CommandButton1, of course).

Comment: By the way, my previous comment will START running your code. Can't get what you mean by "stop the code".

Comment: Hi CMArg, Thank you for the input. It make sense to use check box rather than command box. Although the second option given by you to change the workbook_SheetChange is not working. This is basically to record any changes done in the sheet. As this code is written in workbook it is running always but when I create a document at first i do  not want this code to run. So I have to pause the code. Instead I want to do it with command or check box.

Comment: If the check box is clicked then the code should run and then every change in the sheet will be recorded if I have multiple revisions. I hope you got what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not shure about what you want to achieve, but take a look at the following code. Add a checkbox in sheet `LogDetails`, and named it `RecordingControl`. Then add two lines to your code.

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

    If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("LogDetails").OLEObjects("RecordingControl").Object.Value = True Then 'Add this line
        If ActiveSheet.Name <> "LogDetails" Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
            Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = ActiveSheet.Name & "_" & Target.Address(0, 0)
            Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 1).Value = OldVal
            Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 2).Value = Target.Value
            Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 3).Value = Environ("username")
            Sheets("LogDetails").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 4).Value = Date
            Sheets("LogDetails").Columns("A:E").AutoFit
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If 'Add this line
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi CMArg, Thank you for the help. As this code is active all the time what ever changes I do will be recorded. I just wanted to stop the recording by using click button or any other method. If I am working on new document then all the changes will be recorded which I do not want. I will activate this code only if I want to. Anyway thank you for the help.

Comment: That's what the checkbox does. Clicked: changes recorded. Unclicked: no recording.

Comment: Hi CMArg, Thank you for the help. It is working as expected.